# Adding buttons next to grid

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to have something that looks like this

[image]

This is a paint like program. I have the grid programmed, when I click on a cell it will be painted black, however I can't figure out how to add the buttons next to the grid. I've tried different things but I always get an error message. This is my first time programming in python and using a canvas, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this one.

```
This is the code I have 
from tkinter import *

class Grilla:
    colorCelda = "black"
    colorDefault = "white"
    colorBorde = "black"
    bordeDefault = "black"

    def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size = size
        self.fill = False

    def switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill = not self.fill

    def draw(self):
        # dibujar en el canvas
        if self.master is not None:
            outline = Grilla.colorBorde
            fill = Grilla.colorCelda

            if not self.fill:
                outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
                fill = Grilla.colorDefault

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)

        self.cellSize = tamGrid

        self.grid = []
        for row in range(numFil):

            line = []
            for column in range(numCol):
                line.append(Grilla(self, column, row, tamGrid))

            self.grid.append(line)

        # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        # bind click action
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)

        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _coordenadas(self, event):
        row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
        column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
        return row, column

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]
        cell.switch()
        cell.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()

    # Tamaño de canvas x tamaño de pixeles
    grid = CellGrilla(app, 50, 50, 10)
    grid.pack()

    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you might do it:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Grilla:
    colorCelda = "black"
    colorDefault = "white"
    colorBorde = "black"
    bordeDefault = "black"

    def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size = size
        self.fill = False

    def switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill = not self.fill

    def draw(self):
        # dibujar en el canvas
        if self.master is not None:
            outline = Grilla.colorBorde
            fill = Grilla.colorCelda

            if not self.fill:
                outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
                fill = Grilla.colorDefault

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)

        self.cellSize = tamGrid

        self._grid = []
        for row in range(numFil):

            line = []
            for column in range(numCol):
                line.append(Grilla(master, self, column, row, tamGrid))

            self._grid.append(line)

        # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        # bind click action
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)

        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _coordenadas(self, event):
        row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
        column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
        return row, column

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
        cell = self._grid[row][column]
        cell.switch()
        cell.draw()

    def button1_clicked(self):
        pass

    def button2_clicked(self):
        pass

    def button3_clicked(self):
        pass

    def button4_clicked(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()

    # Tamaño de canvas x tamaño de pixeles
    grid = CellGrilla(app, 50, 50, 10)
    grid.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="news")

    button1 = Button(app, text="Button 1", command=grid.button1_clicked)
    button2 = Button(app, text="Button 2", command=grid.button2_clicked)
    button3 = Button(app, text="Button 3", command=grid.button3_clicked)
    button4 = Button(app, text="Button 4", command=grid.button4_clicked)

    button1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="news")
    button2.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="news")
    button3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="news")
    button4.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="news")

    app.mainloop()
```

I renamed your `<CellGrilla>.grid` variable to `<CellGrilla>._grid` so that later we can use grid instead of pack. The main changes are in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` code. I made your grid take up 4 rows (because you want 4 buttons) and created 4 buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating two frames. One frame is for the grid, the other frame is for the buttons. Use `pack` to put the two frames side-by-side.

Then, you can create the buttons and use `pack` to place them top-to-bottom on the right, and `grid` to create the grid of squares on the left.